# Scabbing joists

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, extension

[image]
I wanted to remove a load-bearing wall and when I opened it up, I learned that the wall is on top of the basement ceiling joists, one foot away from the steel beam. The structure engineer suggested using a flush beam with posts sitting on top of the steel beam. However, the joists are short almost 8 inches and I need to extend all 11 joists to attach them to the lvl beam. Is that doable and makes sense?

Comment: You have an engineer there who knows the house and you are asking a brunch of internet hammer jockies that do not know your house for advice?  Question does not make much sense without pictures/diagrams of what you are asking.

Comment: Question makes much more sense now with the picture.  Might be able to sister the short joists to extend them, but will need to go by what your engineer wants.  Maybe they want new longer joists to reach the extra space, instead of sistering.  You are talking about some of the main structural members holding up your house.